# Why doesn't my function to check valid date work?

Tags: javascript

So I made a script that checks on keyup of input field, if the date is valid. If it matches the regular expression, it should add class `date-valid` so that the borders turn green (added in stylesheet).

My code:

```js
document.getElementById("date-check").addEventListener("keyup", dateValid);

function dateValid() {
 var dateinput = document.getElementById("date-check");

    // regular expression to match required date format
    re = /^\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{4}$/;

    if(!dateinput.value.match(re)) {
      dateinput.classList.add('valid-date');
    }
}
```

```css
input[type="date"].valid-date {
border: 1px solid green; 
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date-check" class="form-control calender-black" name="dbfield52">
```

The problem is, now it checks if it doesn't match the regular expression and then add the border. But it should add the border if it matches the reg. When I change it to `if(dateinput.value.match(re))` it doesn't work.

Comment: With `type="date"` and a browser that supports it, the user cannot choose the format of the date, the browser does for him.

Comment: Why [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)? Use [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) when you only need `true`/`false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the value is not what you see

```js
const re = /^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$/; // 2020-07-10 is what I get in Chrome for value
document.getElementById("date-check").addEventListener("change", dateValid);

function dateValid() {
  console.log(this.value, re.test(this.value));
  this.classList.toggle('valid-date', re.test(this.value));
}
```

```css
.valid-date {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date-check" class="form-control calender-black" name="dbfield52">
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of this. Now it works perfectly, thanks!